# ffmpeg adding ass subtitles: error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args ''

Tags: ffmpeg

So I want to convert my mkv files to mp4 with hardcoded subs

While this works fine:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "[X] File - 1 [Y].mkv" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 2750k -pass 1 -c:a aac "file_out.mp4"
```

When I want to add the ASS subtitles (from the same MKV file) like so:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "[X] File - 1 [Y].mkv" -vf subtitles="[X] File - 1 [Y].mkv" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 2750k -pass 1 -c:a aac "file_out.mp4"
```

the following error is produced:

```
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 00000000259c840] No filename provided!
[AVFilterGraph @ 000000000094dc20] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args ''
```

It seems like somehow it didn't pick up the filename for the subtitles. So what's the deal with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I fixed it already by doing the following instead of `-vf ...` :

`-filter_complex "subtitles='[X] File - 1 [Y].mkv'"`

If you want to use a path, then use the following (forward slashes):

`-filter_complex "subtitles='X\:/Users/~/[X] File - 1 [Y].mkv'"`

Comment: Oh dear lord, thank you for the hint on how to use a full path with `subtitles=` this was driving me mad. Replace the back slashes with forward AND also ESCAPE the drive letter colon!

Answer (score 2):

For me this syntax works

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\USER\Downloads\output.mp4 -filter_complex "subtitles='C\:/Users/USER/Downloads/subtitle.srt'" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k C:\Users\USER\Downloads\foutput.mp4
```

Comment: You don't need `-strict experimental`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi solved a big problem i had with generating subtitles for my mp4.

So if u have a .srt file and a ready .mp4 file this post can help u.

btw this is for => Asp netcore c# maybe it'll work for other c# apps aswell

So u all have probably figured out that putting in the path of a .srt leads to very big problems.

So this is what u should do.

use the cmd to first go to the folder where the .srt file is located and in the command only put the filename subtitles=subtitle.srt. the other video input and output can be regular paths absolute or relative doesnt matter i think it was the subtitles that were problematic

```
\\this is my code for this 

 public async Task ExecuteFFmpegCommand(string video_path)
 {
     // ffmpeg -i [video_path] -vf subtitles=[srt_path] [output_path]

     string srt_path = "subtitle.srt";
     string ffmpegExecutablePath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Xtra_Dependencies", "FFMPEG", "ffmpeg.exe");
     string output_path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "generated", "video", "subbed_video.mp4");
     string commandArguments = $"ffmpeg -i {video_path} -vf subtitles={srt_path} {output_path}";
     string parentDirectory = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "generated", "subtitles");

     try
     {
         var process = new Process
         {
             StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
             {
                 FileName = "cmd.exe",
                 Arguments = $"/c cd \"{parentDirectory}\" && {commandArguments}",
                 RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                 UseShellExecute = false,
                 CreateNoWindow = true,
                 WorkingDirectory = parentDirectory
             }
         };

         process.Start();
         await process.WaitForExitAsync();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         // Handle any exceptions that occur
         Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
     }
 }
```

I hope this was helpfull